# Windows 10 so slow after August 2020 update. It's ridiculous

Tags: hard-drive, boot, google-chrome, performance, unresponsive

I tried to revert back to the 21st of August, but Windows gets stuck in an endless loop after boot. So the revert back never happens.

Before this major update my laptop computer was smooth and fine, and also had no 100% HD usage in Task Manager. I've tried all the things that are suggested online: MSISupported=0, driver updates and so on. Even tried some old drivers without any luck.

Chromium is new after update, and Google Chrome is very slow.

What I have done, during my attempt to get no 100% disk usage:

- Updated AHCI Controller to iaStorA.sys, Intel Graphics driver, GEForce driver
- Disabled WSearch, Superfetch and Prefetch services. And some other services like Adobe Acrobat update, NVIDIA Telemetry Container, App Readiness, MonectServerService, Telephony, ouch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service++
- I've disabled Windows Update.
- I've installed new Toshiba drivers for my laptop HDD.
- Runned Glarysofts Defrag a dozen of times.
- Disabled boot slowdowns (in msconfig).
- I've fixed heating problems by buying a usb-fan.
- Improved Google Chromes Performance by enabling hardware acceleration for videos (youtube, twitch etc).
- Runned CCleaner a dozen of times.

Anyone else had this problem after the August update and anyone managed to fix it? And if so, what are the steps?

My PC & Windows specs:

- Acer Aspire E1-571G

  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz  2.59GHz
  - RAM 4,00 GB
  - 64-bit OS, x64 based processor
  - Toshiba MQ01ABD075
  - Intel(R) 7 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
  - Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
  - NVIDIA GeForce 710M
- Windows version

  - Windows 10 Home
  - Version 2004 (OS-build 10.0.19041.421)

***Edit**: I've also tried to uninstall the latest Windows Updates: KB. From Control Panel->Add remove programs. Some updates are even uninstallable. I've also gotten several Bluescreens the last few days. I fixed it by a command prompt fix.*

Comment: What version of Windows are you running. Production V2004 build 19041 was last updated Aug 11.  To get to an August 20 update means you may be running Windows Insider. I have that on another machine here. If Windows Insider, there may be some legacy software it does not like.

Comment: Not to sound condescending, but what are your PC specs and how old is it? That could have a very large impact on its performance. You could also be misattributing the slowness to the Windows update, where it may be (by coincidence) caused by something else, like a failing hard disk. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: I've updated the specs. Might be that I am running Windows Insider, but I know I remember that I turned it off earlier. Maybe it went back on, somehow. Yes I am running 19041. It actually runs a littlebit faster after i uninstalled some of the August KB-packs. Ill see the next few days how Windows behaves. Thanks.

Comment: Your machine will run Windows 10 just fine. Look for legacy software and/or software not compliant with Windows. There was no general update for Windows build 19041 after Aug 11, so look for other kinds of updates that were installed after.

Comment: Try running DISM.   First:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  then Second:  dism.exe  /online   /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  When both are complete, restart and check.

Comment: @John Yes. I did the /startcomponentcleanup yesterday. the /restorehealth ive done many times the past week. It feels that the problems are mostly gone now, but it is still Chrome is using alot of RAM and disk usage when I run that. Ill try and find out if its only Chrome that is the cause of problem right now.

Comment: Please let us know if the answers have been helpful to you. If so, the comments can be rendered into an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very difficult to know if something has helped or not. The 100% disk usage problem seems a bit random. When the computer is idle 100% pops up like there is something running in the background. Everything helps in a minor way though. Seems that trying out all of the suggestions helps in a minor way. Ive tried almost all I could find online to try to fix it. And somehow Windows has started to run a little bit smoother. I cant say what has helped in a big way until a few days have passed, because I might be wrong that it is totally gone right now, if it pops up again.

Comment: Not trying to be flip, but: 5400 RPM spinning disk, 4GB RAM and Chrome .. how was that ever not slow? System is ripe for high disk utilization.

Comment: Others have noted this, and I agree: your computer may meet the minimum specifications for Windows 10, but that doesn't mean it'll run it well. The slightest load on the system will slow it down significantly

Comment: I found a potential bottleneck. And it was Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver Product number: 11.5.0.1184. I need a couple of days to confirm this though. Before I uninstalled IRST, I uninstalled a few other things that had a minor impact on the performance, I will reinstall these without reinstalling IRST and see if it is true.

Comment: @copper.hat but do you have 100% disk usage in that case or?

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy I will delete my comment. This morning the Chrome menu works normally.

Comment: After several bluescreens I was unable to bootup or even repair, or rollback. 100% disk usage is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install did the trick. I made a bootable usb stick using the [Create Windows 10 Media tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). I used the option to delete all Windows files and create a fresh install of Windows. The problem with this option is that you need to have a backup computer or some device that can access the internet, download the tool and make the bootable usb stick. If you don't have that then you could ask a friend do it for you or ask if some repair shop can do it. I wouldnt have been able to do it without the old laptop I had  lying around. For Home users, currently the latest version of Windows is **10.0.19041 Build 19041** this should work pretty good.

There is no need to change the **Standard SATA AHCI-controller driver** if you have an HDD.
Basically what I have is the **storahci.sys** driver, and I needed not change this after fresh install.

It seemed to me that; all the updates during the past two years or so over the older Windows Home version may have caused 100% diskusage, perhaps due to conflicts or poor drivercode. After fresh install I do not have any issues either with RAM or CPU or disk usage anymore. The latest version of Windows seem to have fixed these problems.

Basically I did **not** need to do any of these things:

- MSISupported
- Standard SATA AHCI-controller driver
- Disable AntiVirus program
- Disable Services and Startup services or change any of these
- Turn of indexing
- Update the graphics drivers (even though this is prefered I didnt have to do it yet)
- Change number of processors for fast boot
- Change anything in the registry
- Do DISM /Online...
- Do sfc /scannow

Windows is booting faster than ever and there is no 100% disk usage anymore.
One last notice: I did update the BIOS firmware on the older version of Windows before it stalled and I had to do a fresh install. And Chrome is also using lesser RAM at the moment. I have no idea if there was a virus in the older version of Windows 10 or if there was some bottleneck issue in some of the older drivers.